# Baggage is shared between threads after Spring Boot 3 migration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, mdc, micrometer-tracing

While migrating from Sleuth to Micrometer, I found a race condition on the update of the MDC context map (complete example can be found [here](https://github.com/dcolazin/reprexes/tree/main/mdc-decorator/mdc-decorator-race)) that boils down to a wrong implementation of the `ExecutorService` responsible for the submitted tasks.

The core logic of the code was unchanged:

```
ExecutorService executorService = buildExecutorService(threads);
List<CompletableFuture<O>> futures = inputList.stream().map(
    input -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
        businessLogic.apply(input), executorService))
    .toList();
CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).get();
```

where the MDC should be updated in the `businessLogic`

```
public Object businessLogic(Object input) {
    BaggageField.getByName(MY_BAGGAGE).updateValue(String.valueOf(input));
    // ...actualBusinessLogic...
}
```

The main change (well, besides the update!) was on how the `ExecutorService` was built:

```
//Spring Boot 2 with Sleuth
private TraceableExecutorService produceExecutor(int threads, String spanName) {
    return new TraceableExecutorService(this.beanFactory,
        Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads), spanName);
}

//Spring Boot 3 with Micrometer
private ExecutorService produceExecutor(int threads) {
    ContextRegistry.getInstance().registerThreadLocalAccessor(new ObservationAwareSpanThreadLocalAccessor(this.tracer));
    return ContextExecutorService.wrap(
        Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads), ContextSnapshot::captureAll);
}
```

The issue is that while `TraceableExecutorService` creates a new span for each invocation of the business logic, the `ContextExecutorService` not only propagates/copies, but *shares* the context between threads (but the MDC is thread-bound, and fun race conditions are ensured!).

Is there a proper way to replicate the old Sleuth behavior (one span for each invocation or thread) without reimplementing from scratch the `TraceableExecutorService`? The [migration docs](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/tracing/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Sleuth-3.1-Migration-Guide#async-instrumentation) don't seem that helpful.

Relevant Github issue [here](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/context-propagation/issues/193).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the only solution is to reimplement `TraceableExecutorService`/`TraceCallable`/`TraceRunnable`, reworking the code from Sleuth, as suggested from the Github issue. No out-of-the-box solution is provided in Micrometer.